# Access to a TextView within a LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, layout, reference, textview

For my android application i had to define a particular layout containing three blank TextView. Next I want to modify the content of these TextView and then append this LinearLayout to another LinearLayout programmatically. My problem is that when I try to reference to a TextView inside my inner Layout i got NULL pointer exception.

This is my inner Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:id="@+id/firstRowLinearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/matchTextView"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/resultTextView"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/quoteTextView"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the code where I try to access to the TextView inside this layout:

```
LinearLayout couponLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)  findViewById(R.id.couponLinearLayout);   // outer layout

        LinearLayout test = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.firstRowLinearLayout);      // layout to be added to the outer one

        TextView first_field = (TextView) test.findViewById(R.id.matchTextView);
(R.id.resultTextView);

        first_field.setText("TEST");

        couponLinearLayout.addView(test);
```

Using this code i got, as I said, a NULL pointer exception when I define the TextView. Hope that you can help me!

Comment: where is your `couponLinearLayout` id?

Comment: are you inflating your layout?

Answer (score 0):

**Your Code should be like this**
You forgot to inflate inner layout

```
LinearLayout couponLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)  findViewById(R.id.couponLinearLayout);   // outer layout
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inner_layout,
                            null);
        LinearLayout test = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById (R.id.firstRowLinearLayout);      // layout to be added to the outer one

        TextView first_field = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.matchTextView);


        first_field.setText("TEST");

        couponLinearLayout.addView(test);
```

Comment: what is `(R.id.resultTextView);` below `TextView first_field `?

Comment: I will try soon your code, but I can't understand what "activity" refers to : what I have to use, my activity name?

Comment: activity is object of your Activity name.
you can do like :
Activity activity;
in onCreate(.... method assign that object.
activity=this;